# Simple way which allows to put a restriction on Multiline Field

Tags: 2013

Apart from Event System C# Coding, is there any other simple way which allows to put a restriction on Multiline Field.

Comment: What restriction are you talking about? You can do a lot in your XSD schema, like number of characters in the field or so

Answer (score 2):

As stated by user978511 (hi Andrey) there are quite a few other options, it really depends on the type of restriction.

See some examples [here](http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2012/07/validating-content-on-save-part-1-of.html) using XSD and Event System and [here](http://www.curlette.com/?p=913) using a GUI Extension.

Answer (score 2):

As @Nuno and @Andrey say it depends on the type of restriction.

For Rich Text Formatting Multiline fields, Tridion has inbuilt functionality to limit `allowed actions`, `allowed styles` and execute an `XSLT formatting` on save. It also allows you to enforce an `HTML document type` and `accessibility level`

[image]

To access these setting, open your `Schema`, select the desired `Field`, and scroll down to the `Field Details` section